# node jitsu cannot find local modules

Tags: node.js, nodejitsu

I have an application successfully working locally so I know the code works. However when I go to deploy to node jitsu I get an error that it cannot find a local module. Here is what I have:

**File Setup:**

```
/index.js
/config/config.js
```

**index.js**

```
var cfg = require('./config/config.js');
```

When trying to deploy node jitsu is giving me an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './config/config.js'
```

Since all this code works locally I do not believe this is a coding issue. I am under the impression that local modules do not need to be included in package.json but perhaps they do for node jitsu? I read their documentation but cannot find anything special for local modules.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Local modules like this should work properly.. so long as you don't have it in `.gitignore` or `.npmignore`.

Modules in the `node_modules` directory require that you add it to the `bundledDependencies` array in your `package.json` file.

An easy way to check for whether the file is included in your deploy is to run `tar -tf $(npm pack)`.

Comment: .gitignore had the config.js filename listed in there. Removing that from .gitignore resolved the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: You could also add an `.npmignore` file if you want to keep it in `.gitignore`, and exclusively allow it. `.npmignore` follows the same format as `.gitignore`, so a simple `!./config/config.js` should work.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same error on deploy, but caused by a different root cause. In case anybody stumbles into the same problem:

**File Setup:**

```
/public/Data/TargetData.js
```

**app.js require statement:**

```
var target = require('./public/data/TargetData.js');
```

My local Mac OSX environment allowed the capitalization difference of `/data/` vs. `/Data/` - the Nodejitsu server did not.

Comment: Man thanks for posting this, saved me a bunch of time.